# Two jQuery requests to servlet

Tags: java, jquery, servlets

I have a jQuery request:

```
handler: function(){
 formp.getForm().submit({
 url: url_servlet+'uploadfile',
 success: function(formp, o) {
  if(o.result.file!=""){
  alert(o.result.file);
 }
   }
  })
}
```

I servlet i get this request: upload file and call Java class to read it:

```
public class Read{
  public static String ReadFile (String filePath) throws IOException, SchemaException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

//****FILE READ PART***//


//****INPUT DATA TO DATA BASE****//
  }
}
```

So i have two stages in my java class. Now after `Reading file` stage i want to send parameter to client after i want to get answer and call `input data to DB` stage and send parameter to client again.
Its possible to do?

**UPDATE**

I think i gonna create another method in my class to just a read file. 
But i have a question: After this method work i send parameters in client after i make another jQuery request to servlet and call another method of ly java class. Class fields save they values which they take in work of first method?

Comment: I think you are tryin to do this : : Upload File >> Read File >> Send Parameter to client ... Right ?

Comment: Yeah i write this in question.

Comment: Do your best to keep the server stateless.  Have two forms, one which submits the file to read the parameters from and the other to make your final request with parameters.  Use jQuery to update form #2.  [See here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for information how to send and receive parameters.

Comment: Its a big problem. Becouse to input data to DB i gonna take some parametrs from fileread part.

Comment: Its mean that i gonna create another java class with jast a read file part.

Comment: Save yourself some trouble and use [apache file upload library](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).

Comment: i use it for upload. To Read Tile part i mean that i take data from this file.